# Joomla custom Module File Form Field Type destination

Tags: php, xml, file-upload, joomla, joomla-module

Basically i am making a custom joomla module that displays CSVs in the website. The CSV is uploaded by the administrator from the backend. In the xml file, i have this:

```
<field name="testfield" type="file" label="CSV file" description="Upload a CSV file to display" />
```

However,  when i echo this field in the mod_csv.php:

```
$testfield      =$params->get( 'testfield' );
<?php echo($testfield)?>
```

It only displays the filename. Basically I want to know how to determine where this file is uploaded, so that I can retrieve the path of the CSV file uploaded. I have very poor php skills, and to create this module i just took another module and altered it to suit my needs.

Thank you!

Comment: The CSV file is not uploaded to anywhere in the joomla website directory. I want to know how to determine where to upload it because it is not even uploaded anywhere.

Comment: If I am getting correctly than you should know that File field has nothing to do with path.You have to check if uploading functionality is written or not.If yes,then copy path from there or implement the functionality.